# Apache throwing 403 on www.example.com/dir/.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I've discovered from Google Webmaster Tools that Google has found a bad link somewhere that is throwing a 403 error on my server.

The url is like this:

http://www.example.com/directory/.php

I don't know how that url has come about and the site is too complicated for me to find out, but I'd like to simply place a 301 redirect to:

http://www.example.com/directory/

I've put the correct rule in .htaccess for the redirect, but it doesn't appear to be triggered. It's almost as if the 403 is being generated before .htaccess is processed. Does anyone know why this might be and how I can successfully get the user redirected to the new page?

Comment: Could you paste your 'correct rule', as it may not be correct if it is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the fact that the rule may be indeed incorrect, this could also be because this involves looking for a file with a filename starting with a `.`.
These files are usually "hidden" from the outside world, so it might be that either your Apache (configuration) or your OS does not allow serving this file.

Without knowing more about the configuration, this cannot be analyzed though. You could test it by creating a file called ".test" and see if that's reachable.

Comment: My rule is as follows:   

`Redirect 301 /directory/.php http://www.example.com/directory/`  

I created a file called .test and I can access it fine.   

Do you know where I should look in my configuration to find out what may be blocked from seeing it? Note that I do not wish to serve this file, just create a 301 redirect to another file if a user enters that URL.

Comment: And did you put this rule in a `.htaccess` inside `/directory/` or in `/`? And did you not forget to also include `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: I put it inside `/` This is where all my rules are, I have many similar ones. `RewriteEngine on` is set

Comment: But does the `Redirect` directive work on files?

I'd make it the following, I think:
`RewriteRule ^directory/\.php$ http://www.example.com/directory/ [L]`